# Why state with type number make 0 when I click on backspace?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a state:

```
const [constructionYear, setConstructionYear] = useState<number>(1919)
```

This is my `change` event handler:

```
 const onConstructionYearChange = ({ currentTarget }: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const value = currentTarget.value

    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
    const isValidValue = isInteger(String(value)) && +value <= currentYear

    if (isValidValue) {
      currentTarget.setCustomValidity("")
      setConstructionYear(+value)
    } else {
      currentTarget.setCustomValidity("Bitte ein gültiges Jahr eingeben")
      currentTarget.reportValidity()
    }
  }
```

The problem is when I click the backspace and the input becomes empty it provides a fixed on 0 ( it converts '' to 0 )

[image]

I want to give the user the ability to clear the whole field.

When making the type as:

```
const [constructionYear, setConstructionYear] = useState<number|string>(1919)
```

and add this line to handler:

```
    if (!currentTarget.value) {
      setConstructionYear("")
    }
```

[image]

It works well.

Is there another way without adding the string type to the state?

Comment: `isInteger(String(value))` is `isInteger` a custom function? `Number.isInteger(String(1919))` will returns **false** in all scenarios since it will alway be a string.

Comment: this is my isInteger `export const isInteger = (value: string) => {
  const pattern = /^\d*$/
  return pattern.test(value)
}`

Comment: I see. Your function `isInteger('')` returns **true** for an empty string. Then `+''` will be casted to `0`

Comment: YES. what is your suggestion?

Comment: Try replacing `/^\d*$/` with `/^\d+$/`  (`+` : at least one occurence, `*`: Any number of occurences, including none)

Comment: The same issue, the zero remains.

Comment: It sounds like you want a placeholder, which for HTML input elements is done through the `placeholder` attribute. For your current code however, I'd also use `Number.isInteger` rather than your own function (unless it was statically imported), since `Number.isInteger('') === false`. From there, you can provide an error message for non-numeric input and return from the function, _before_ you end up doing any of the code treating the input as a number.